# Enable middle click with 3 finger click on synaptics touchpad

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, synaptics-touchpad

I have a dell xps 15 9530 with a synaptics touchpad running windows 10

I used to have another dell where I could 3 finger click and trigger a middle click. I've tried a few registry tweaks, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've got 3 finger tap working, but multi finger taps are really finicky and only work around 80% of the time.

Does anybody know the proper registry edits?

Comment: If you're willing to use a 3rd party software, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/3ri4pm/enable_3finger_tap_as_middle_click_on_xps_15_and/) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It's super weird because I literally just read that thread a few hours before you posted this comment.  For some reason autohotkey didn't work for me.  I created another post on reddit with no luck.  But I did figure it out yesterday after tinkering with the registry for a while.  Thanks

Comment: This should be a feature within the OEM Synaptics driver and can be accessed via the Synaptics control panel: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items` → Mouse → Tab: _Device Settings_ → _Settings_

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a long time, I finally got it working exactly how I want it to.

I'm still on my XPS 15, running Windows 10 AU.

Essentially what I did was go through the registry and update all values of `3FingerPressButtonAction`, `3FingerPressPlugInActionID`, `3FClickAction`, and `MiddleButtonAction`

I'm not 100% sure if all the changes are necessary, but I know that each one individually won't do the trick.